# Windows 10 store application submission / Restricted capabilities

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, windows-store-apps, submission

Recently my vb.net application submission with the following response from the microsoft which i could not find the solution anywhere

> ### Capabilities: 10.6 Restricted Capability
>
> #### You do not have approval to use the following restricted capabilities runFullTrust. App fails to launch. just-in-time (JIT)
>
> debugging instead of this dialog box. The application must also be
> compiled with debugging enabled.
>
> ### Capabilities: 10 Centennial Permissions
>
> #### Your app uses the RunFullTrust permission but has not been approved for the permission by Microsoft.

Please find some copy of the codes below which is kind of a tool which is reading xml data from the webpage and showing it to the tool. My only concern is i have to read the system globalization culture info and temporary change it to the format that has to be used by tool and convert it to the original settings while the user close the application

```
  'Current user settings 
Private currentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Programın çalıştırıldıgı bilgisayardaki Tarih ve saat ayarları istenilen formata getirilir
    Dim tmpCurrentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
    tmpCurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

    'Culture is set back to its original value when form closes 
    currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

    tmpCurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy dddd"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = tmpCurrentCulture

    ' internet bağlantısı kontrol edilir

    Try

    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.google.com") Then
```

Please also find some part from app. manifest file ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
```

How to make the necessary changes in order to re-submit the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your manifest declares the **runFullTrust** capability,the Dev center will rigger the internal process to evaluate the request when it analyze the package.You can refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/07/13/a-simpler-and-faster-way-to-publish-your-desktop-bridge-applications-on-the-microsoft-store/) for more details on the submission process.

After you upload the package in the **Package** page,a warning will appear, as shown in following picture.
[image: warning]
In the **submission** page, there is a statement below the submission options, see the picture:
[image: statement]
Please filled reason why do you need the runFullTrust capability, and how will it be used in your product in the **submission options** page,as shown in following picture:
[image: how to]

Comment: I am checking the description of the restricted capability list from here ;https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#restricted-capabilities but non of them are matching with my program, i really dont understand why i need runfulltrust capability still?

Comment: I also fill that part during the submission stage as you mentioned above ( which i did not remember the full text that i wrote ) with saying that my application is so simple that just getting the info from the web (xml) and showing it to the user. But i really dont understand the reason that why that kind of simple application requires fulltrust. Appreciate if you can help me, just let me know if i should share here the full codes of the program to analyze

Comment: According to your description,your app is a vb.net app and it may need to be converted to desktop bridge app to  publish in the Store.You can read this doc(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root). The desktop bridge app is always with the runFullTrust capability.

Comment: Again thank you, which that means explanation part during the submission by saying this is the desktop bridge app should be enough. ( which i did and failed). Do you know how can compile my application with debugging enabled?